# Any good tool to determine focus and lexical answer type?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I'm looking for a tool which can automatically extract what is being asked for from a natural language question. For example, "Who is the First Lady of the United States", of which the focus is First Lady. With this function I can develop a question answering application. Is there any tool that can be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a general tool out there that can offer this functionality but there exists a book which teaches these principles and also provides a fantastic tutorial which is to build a "Question Answering System" which is what you are looking for.

You can find out more about the book [here](https://www.manning.com/books/taming-text).

The book provides code samples and step by step instructions on how to complete the tool. This might help you out.

Comment: I've tried that book but it is a bit far from what I want. Essentially I need an extractor which can extract triples from a sentence. Eg. "Which movie was directed by James Cameron and acted by Leonardo DiCaprio". I've tried Stanford OpenIE but it did not work well with questions.